# Find the inverse result from the combination of inverse and scalar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A scalar matrix is a square matrix of the form $S=aI_n$ where $I_n$ is the n×n identity matrix and a ∈ R.  If S is a nonzero scalar matrix and N is a nilpotent matrix with $N^2= 0$, find the inverse of the matrix A=S+N.  (Hint: Try a linear combination of S and N for the inverse of A.)

I'm just learning about types of matrix and having this question on my practice. I think according to the hint, I need to write the inverse of A like this: $A^{-1} = xS + yN$ and try to figure out what x and y is. So I'm currently stuck here, can you guys help me out. All helps is appreaciate.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the product? You will probably need to use that $S$ commutes with $N$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by expanding the product? I'm trying to substitute S and N into the function but I'm still stuck here

Comment: You want the product $(S+N)(xS+yN)$ to be $I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This winds up being pretty straightforward with the hints in the comments, by @HereToRelax.

You get $(S+N)(xS+yN)=xS^2+(x+y)SN+yN^2=xS^2+(x+y)SN$.  Now if we choose $x=1/a^2$ and $y=-x$, we get it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you explain why $x = 1/a^2$ and y = -x to me?

Comment: Yeah, then we the identity, as we want.  Namely, $1/a^2S^2=I$.  And the other term vanishes because we have $(y+x)SN=0\cdot SN=0$.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot

Comment: You bet.  The hint really helped here.